# beginner: Boostrap modal not working inside a collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hello I am working on a school project that requires to use only bootstrap. I have a collapse element and inside are photos that are supposed to view the full image on click (the modal). I used the code directly from the bootstrap site. However when I click to launch the modal, it does appear but the page is dimmed and could not click anywhere to exit.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
```

```
<p>  
    <button class="btn btn-light” type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <img class="d-block w-100 img-responsive" src="picA.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </button>
</p>
  <div class="card-body container center">


        <button class="btn btn-light none” type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            <h4 class="card-title">SERIES TITLE</h4>
        </button>

        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="row container" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">

            <div class="col">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                    <img class="card-img-top thumb" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/545470/pexels-photo-545470.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb">
                </a>

                      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                             <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/545470/pexels-photo-545470.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">Modal Footer Content
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                      </div><!-- /.modal -->                        
            </div>
```

Comment: Do not post the code as image.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen you `html` code. It is okay. May be you should check jQuery and Bootstrap library load properly or not.

Check load properly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then your put your html. I didn't change anything.

```
    <p>  
        <button class="btn btn-light” type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      <img class="d-block w-100 img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="First slide">
        </button>
    </p>
      <div class="card-body container center">


            <button class="btn btn-light none” type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <h4 class="card-title">SERIES TITLE</h4>
            </button>

            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="row container" style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">

            <div class="col">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                     <img class="card-img-top thumb" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
                </a>

                      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                             <img class="img-fluid" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">Modal Footer Content
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                      </div><!-- /.modal -->                        
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```